# Submit form data into google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to add some data in form of html form table into a spreadsheet by matching some values.

But somehow Submit button does nothing.

Code.gs --->

```
function openInputDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .showModalDialog(html, 'Add Item');
}

function itemAdd(form) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var match1 = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();


    for (var i = 0; i = 300; i++)

    {
        if (lastRow - i == match1) {
            sheet.getRange(lastRow - i, 2, 1, 1).setValues(form.details);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

index.Html ----->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<br>
<form>
    Details:<br>
    <input type="text" name="details">
    <br> Quantity:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

</html>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share the copy of your spreadsheet

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wSrOwjRcmMsFkACmJTHPE3qJxCLCUW9rwQtvv3PEjDA/edit?usp=sharing) here is the link to my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....Replace the `itemAdd` function

```
function itemAdd(form) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var match1 = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1,lastRow).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<dataRange.length;i++){
        if(dataRange[i][0] == match1){
            sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(form.details)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys it worked smoothly. Really appreciate your efforts for solving my issue. Warm regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function localItemAdd()
    {
       var i1=$('#d').val();//it is helpful to use intermediate values when debugging new code
       var i2=$('#q').val();
       var A={};
       A['details']=i1;
       A['quantity']=i2;
       google.script.run.itemAdd(A);
    }
    console.log('My Code'); //this make it easier to find your code in the debugger console
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    Details:<br><input id="d" type="text" name="details" />
    <br> Quantity:<br><input id="q" type="text" name="quantity" />
    <br><br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="localItemAdd();google.script.host.close();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well Thanks for the support. However this does not solve the purpose the code should get values from cell "B2" and then loop and match in cell "A6" if found then paste the form value (form.detail) in cell "B6"